# Product Attribute vs Product Attribute Assigned

Tags: product-attribute, price-rules

**Shopping Cart Price Rules**

Magento version: 1.14.2.0

What is the difference between Product Attribute and Product Attribute Assigned sections in *Conditions* tab when creating a rule?

Both contain same set of options to select from but what is the difference between the two.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two sections is the following:

- The `Product Attribute` entries can be used to select products based on the *value* of a product attribute, using one the following operators: `is`, `is not`, `equals or greater than`, `equals or less than`, `greater than`, `less than`, `contains`, `does not contain`, `is one of` and `is not one of` (the input type of the product attribute determines which of these operators can be used).
- The `Product Attribute Assigned` entries can be used to select products based on whether or not a product attribute is a *assigned* to a product. Looking at the actual implementation of the `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Product_Attribute_Assigned::validate` method, a product attribute is assigned to a product when both of the following conditions are met:

  1. The attribute is contained in the product's *attribute set*.
  2. The product's product type is contained in the attribute's *applicable product types*.